# Getting 'Unmet dependencies' error when updating Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: upgrade, dependencies

I am getting an 'Unmet dependencies' error when running 'sudo apt upgrade'.  I have tried running 'apt --fix-broken install', but get the following output.

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-46-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0 linux-tools
  linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-46-generic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-46-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 323 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic: dependency problems, but removing anyway as
 you requested:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-46-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic | linu
x-image-unsigned-5.15.0-46-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic is to be removed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-46-generic is not installed.

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04' missi
ng; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-generic-hwe-22.04' missing; as
suming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-generic' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-generic' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-firmware' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-generic-hwe-20.04' missing; as
suming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 198228 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic (5.15.0-46.49) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-48-generic
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.s
o.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic package post-removal script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm a bit of a newbie to Linux, but I'm trying to learn.  If you have ideas or resources to send my way about fixing this type of problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you use grub-customizer?

Comment: @nobody Yes, I did use grub-customizer when I installed ubuntu for dual boot with windows.

Comment: I hate this tool.  Please mv any file in `/etc/grub.d` with proxy in name to a folder in your $HOME you have it to do with sudo.  Then try `sudo apt  - f install`

Comment: @nobody that worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help.